# Numba parallel option: "key already in dictionary" problem

Tags: python, parallel-processing, numba

I have the following function, which numba cannot compile when I had the `parallel=True` option.

```
@njit(nopython=True, nogil=True, cache=True, parallel=True)
def corrected_jacobian_numba_icecore(age_top_sigma,
                             accu, tau, lid, dens, dens_firn,
                             depth, depth_inter, depth_mid,
                             age, airage, age_model, airage_model,
                             ice_equiv_depth,
                             agedens, icelayerthick,
                             corr_a, corr_tau, corr_lid,
                             chol_a, chol_tau, chol_lid,
                             sigmap_corr_a, sigmap_corr_tau, sigmap_corr_lid,
                             corr_a_age, corr_tau_depth, corr_lid_age):

    age_jac = np.zeros((1+len(corr_a)+len(corr_tau)+len(corr_lid), len(age)))
    age_jac[0, :] = age_top_sigma * np.ones(len(age))       
    airage_jac = np.zeros((1+len(corr_a)+len(corr_tau)+len(corr_lid), len(airage)))
    airage_jac[0, :] = age_top_sigma * np.ones(len(airage))       
    delta_depth_jac = np.zeros((1+len(corr_a)+len(corr_tau)+len(corr_lid), len(depth)))
#    delta_depth[0, :] = age_top_sigma * np.zeros(len(depth))  # useless

    for i in prange(len(corr_a)):

        corr_a_vec = np.zeros(len(corr_a))
        corr_a_vec[i] = 1.
    #Accu
        corr_vec = np.dot(chol_a, corr_a_vec)*sigmap_corr_a
        toto = np.interp((age_model[:-1]+age_model[1:])/2,
                                  corr_a_age, corr_vec)
        agedens_vec = - toto * agedens

    #Ice age
        age_vec = np.cumsum(np.concatenate((np.array([0]), depth_inter*agedens_vec)))
        age_jac[1+i,:] = age_vec

    #Air age
        airage_vec = np.interp(ice_equiv_depth, depth, age_vec)
        airage_jac[1+i, :] = airage_vec
        # delta_depth_vec = np.zeros_like(depth)
        # delta_depth_jac[1+i, :] = delta_depth_vec
            

        
    for i in prange(len(corr_tau)):
                        
        corr_tau_vec = np.zeros(len(corr_tau))
        corr_tau_vec[i] = 1.
        corr_vec = np.dot(chol_tau, corr_tau_vec)*sigmap_corr_tau
        tata = np.interp(depth_mid, corr_tau_depth, corr_vec)
        agedens_vec = -tata * agedens                
        age_vec = np.cumsum(np.concatenate((np.array([0]), depth_inter*agedens_vec)))
        age_jac[1+len(corr_a)+i, :] = age_vec
        
        thin_vec = -tata * dens/tau
        udepth_vec = np.cumsum(np.concatenate((np.array([0]), depth_inter*thin_vec)))
        delta_depth_vec = - np.interp(ice_equiv_depth, depth_mid,
                                      tau/dens) * (udepth_vec - \
                                    np.interp(ice_equiv_depth, depth, udepth_vec))
        airage_vec = np.interp(ice_equiv_depth, depth, age_vec) \
                        - np.interp(ice_equiv_depth, depth_mid, agedens) * \
                        delta_depth_vec
        airage_jac[1+len(corr_a)+i, :] = airage_vec
        delta_depth_jac[1+len(corr_a)+i, :] = delta_depth_vec

        #To be continued...                

    for i in prange(len(corr_lid)):

        age_vec = np.zeros_like(depth)
        age_jac[1+len(corr_a)+len(corr_tau)+i, :] = age_vec

        corr_lid_vec = np.zeros(len(corr_lid))
        corr_lid_vec[i] = 1.
        corr_vec = np.dot(chol_lid, corr_lid_vec)*sigmap_corr_lid
        lid_vec = np.interp(airage_model, corr_lid_age, corr_vec) * lid
        delta_depth_vec = dens_firn * lid_vec * \
                            np.interp(ice_equiv_depth, depth_mid, 
                                      tau/dens)
        airage_vec = - np.interp(ice_equiv_depth, depth_mid, 
                                  agedens) * delta_depth_vec
        airage_jac[1+len(corr_a)+len(corr_tau)+i, :] = airage_vec
        delta_depth_jac[1+len(corr_a)+len(corr_tau)+i, :] = delta_depth_vec

    return airage_jac, delta_depth_jac, age_jac
```

The error message is

```
AssertionError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython rewrites)
key already in dictionary: '$np_typ_var.1'
```

I am using python-3.11 from anaconda.

I tried to compile this code with numba and the parallel=True option.
I was expecting it to work since there is nothing very fancy in my code.

Comment: see [how to create a Minimal, Reproducible, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), what are the arguments you're passing to this function?

Comment: It looks like a Numba internal error (`prange` is still not very stable as of today in practice). Out of curiosity: can you try to use different variable names in your 3 parallel loops?